# PostgreSQL / PostGIS using a variables in a query

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am trying to access a point and get the inpsectors name for it . The query by it`s self works fine but I need the Longitude and Latitude to be variables as the Lng and Lat will change .

This is what I have

```
DO $$
DECLARE
   longitude text := -4.323966436509;
   latitiude text := 51.857052145748;
BEGIN 
    --RAISE NOTICE '% %', longitude, latitiude;
    SELECT inspectors_name as Name  
    FROM ccc_transport_streets."Inspectors_Areas_polygon" 
    WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_Transform (ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(lonitude latitiude)',4326), 27700));
END $$;
```

However I get the error :-

> ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry HINT:  "POINT(lo" <-- parse
>   error at position 8 within geometry

I have changed the data type to float too. Any ideas pretty new Postgresql .

Answer (score 1):

To create point use st_makepoint() function. Then set SRID for point and then check if polygon contains that point.

```
DO $$
    DECLARE
       longitude numeric := -4.323966436509;
       latitiude numeric := 51.857052145748;
    BEGIN 
        --RAISE NOTICE '% %', longitude, latitiude;
        SELECT inspectors_name as Name  
        FROM ccc_transport_streets."Inspectors_Areas_polygon" 
        WHERE ST_Contains(geom, ST_setSRID (st_makePOINT (longitude, latitiude),4326)
);
    END $$;
```